# Continuous Trap Card Monsters VS Face Down Defense Ruling

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I run a Continuous Trap Card/[Paleozoic](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Paleozoic) Trap deck mix.  When battling an opponent who uses [Ghostricks](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Ghostrick) that forces your opponent to face down defense position cards, and my [Tiki Curse](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Tiki_Curse) is out there in face up defense and was flipped to face down defense position.

The player stated the effects are negated and is in face down defense as a monster. So how does it all go?

1. When flipped summon, it will be a monster retaining effects.
2. When its flipped face down, (or even face down defense position),
      returns to the spell/trap zone as a set trap card.
3. When flipped summon, it will be returned to the trap zone as a negated continuous trap card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These Tiki cards and similar (like [Shapesister](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Shapesister)) can be somewhat confusing.

The ruling on [Trap Monsters](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Trap_Monster) indicates the following thing specific to this situation (emphasis mine):

> ... If "Book of Moon" is used against an already active Trap Monster, **the Trap Monster is set as a Trap Card again** and can be activated and Special Summoned the next turn.

So your Tiki Curse actually returns to your Spell/Trap card zone, set.

---

Other important details from that link include:

- > ...and are subsequently **treated as both Monster Cards and Trap Cards**. As such, they **take up both a Monster Zone and a Spell & Trap Zone at the same time**.

  This tells us that they take both a monster and spell/trap zone. Derivated from that fact we have the consequence that they can be destroyed both by effects that destroy monsters or spell/traps (from [this](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Shapesister#TrapMonsterRulings) other link).
- > While active, **a Trap Monster can be destroyed by effects that affect Monsters and/or Spells/Traps**. (You can use either Dark Hole or Heavy Storm to destroy them.)

  Finally, if they are negated, they get caught in some sort of "limbo", where they return to their Trap zone:
- > **If they are negated** with "Jinzo" or "Royal Decree", they will **return to the Spell & Trap Zone as Continuous Trap Cards with no effect**, and will **remain there even after** "Jinzo" or "Royal Decree" are removed.

---

Some further reference on Trap Monsters on [this](https://yugiohblog.konami.com/articles/?p=4062) Konami blog.

Comment: I figured out the answer when consulting to a friend and thought bout doing a Q&A.  But sadly not that high of a rep :'(  But I'm glad you pointed out juicy information :)

Comment: @GarethCompton glad I could help :)

Comment: On another hand @GarethCompton if you are playing paleo, I suggest you drop those Trap Monster, as Paleo cards are different as they are *not* treated as traps after activation

Comment: True but it only enhances their summoning conditions.  I can pretty much swarm the field on my opponents turn.  I know players tell me to try todally awesome cards with paleo.  But I strive away from the full meta ;)