# Can trap monsters and defense zone create a valid field lock?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

The setup is this:

Field spell: [Defense Zone](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Defense_Zone)
Column 1: Any trap monster / [Field Barrier](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Field_Barrier)
Column 2: Any trap monster / [Imperial Custom](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Custom)
Column 3: EMPTY / Reserved zone for trap monster
Column 4: EMPTY / Reserved zone for trap monster
Column 5: (Anything, preferably something that can prevent battle damage)

The logic goes that Field Barrier protects Defense Zone, The trap monsters combined with Defense Zone protect themselves AND Field Barrier / Imperial Custom from destruction and Imperial Custom protects the monsters from battle.

Save for field-wide bounce or sending, **it looks like a perfect lock, but is it rules-legal?**

Comment: Please add links if you mention cards (or even better write their card texts); it makes it a whole lot easier

Comment: Also please state what a field lock is

Comment: Interesting question, I'll add links to the cards you mention for completeness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thorough check on several rulings seems that indeed **this combo is Legal**, although quite hard to actually pull or be realistic to play.

I had my doubts with the monster trap, as they are both trap and monster (except [Paleozoic](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Paleozoic) cards), but found a [ruling](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Imperial_Custom) that states that if imperial custom is up then the trap monster is indestructible:

> If “[Embodiment of Apophis](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Embodiment_of_Apophis)” is being treated as a monster while “Imperial Custom” is active, it cannot be destroyed by effects or battle.

Now, as others mention, this combo is not a flawless lock; your trap monsters are still exposed.

You can get rid of those trap monsters by **banishing** them, **sending** them to GY, **returning to hand/deck**, **flip face-down** (which sets the card as Trap again, as explained [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/41925/22373)), **change control** with other monster, **tributing** them, **attach as XYZ material** (with [Number 101: Silent Honor ARK](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_101:_Silent_Honor_ARK) for example), or **negate their effects** (which [returns](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Shapesister) them to the Trap zone, negated).

Comment: Silent honor DARK is good

Comment: @VortexYT yes, one of the best XYZ monsters out there IMO :) it was also really expensive when it came out (about $50 each). I still got mine, which is 1st edition, and I use in almost all decks I build that have lvl 4 monsters.

Comment: @VortexYT also, combine it with Rank Up Magic: The seventh it's a killer draw.

Comment: Yes. Shame I don't have it... The RUMs aren't that good tbh because ranking up largely require them, and without a lot of CXyz or CXX(X) in the Extra Deck, and the right cards on the field, well, they are pretty unreliable.

Comment: Neither do I have any 10X / C10X

Comment: @VortexYZ well you would be surprised, RUMs can be the top deck you just need

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is valid, and your logic is correct. However, it is not invincible. They can always be returned to the hand, or they can be banished, unless of course you have monsters or spells/traps to prevent this.

The most important part of a Trap Monster that concerns this is **the part that says:** *"This card is also treated as a Trap Card"* This means that even though it is a Monster, it is also treated as a trap, hence being indestructible.

Anything that the rulebook doesn't state makes it valid.

*Now... a card that stops it affects from being negated*

Comment: Correct, this is valid setup. Although adding some backup reference to justify *why* it is valid would help your answer. Added an answer myself with some other details and relevant rulings.

Comment: @DarkCygnus I have already said why it is valid. There are also no other flaws that are caused by card effects being incorrectly interpreted.